# Mock IBM MQ manager

Tags: mocking, load, websphere, ibm-mq

I need to mock **IBM MQ manager** for load testing with auto-replay for some MQ applications.

Are there instruments to do it? Maybe, several instruments for each operation - mock and auto-replay.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by ***mock IBM MQ manager***?

You cannot a fake queue manager.  The best thing to do is to download [IBM MQ for Developers](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/articles/mq-downloads/) (Linux or Windows) and set it up with what queues, channels, etc. you need.  You can also download [IBM MQ Advanced for Developers for Raspberry Pi](https://ibm.biz/mqdevrpi).

Now if you only meant that you want to simulate either server-side or client-side component getting or putting of messages via replaying of messages then have a look at [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html).  MQ Visual Edit can off messages in a queue to an SQLite database file which includes both the MQMD and message data.  Hence, later you can replay those same messages over and over again.  Also, it has 4 different test servers built into it to simulate server-side or client-side components.

Comment: Yes, I mean fake IBM MQ. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say we have a situation like the one described in the diagram below. To be able to load test the "Shopping system" in isolation, you will need access to an IBM MQ broker and a tool to simulate the "Payment processing system".

[image: Payment processing over IBM MQ queues]

To access an IBM MQ broker you have several options:

- Use [IBM MQ for developers](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/articles/mq-downloads) (also available [as a pre-built Docker image on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq)) -  you will need to confirm with your legal team if you can use it for your particular use case (see [license](https://www14.software.ibm.com/cgi-bin/weblap/lap.pl?popup=Y&li_formnum=L-APIG-BMKG5H))
- Use [MQ cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/mq?cm_sp=ibmdev-_-developer-tutorials-_-cloudreg)
- Work closely with your operation's team to allocate resources on an existing IBM MQ broker available in your company

To simulate the "Payment processing system" you can write a tool yourself or use one of the [off-the-shelf tools available called service virtualization tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools).

For example, you can [use Traffic Parrot as it supports IBM MQ](https://trafficparrot.com/tutorials/mocking-or-simulating-jms-ibm-websphere-mq.html).

Keep in mind that the load test like that can provide comparable performance benchmarks and tell if for example if your future code changes or releases are more or less performant. In order to simulate Black Friday scenarios, you will need to consider replicating the whole production environment setup in your load test environment (including allocation the same hardware resources and using the same software versions).